# OpenGL doesn't draw quads with GL_COLOR_ARRAY enabled

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to get the following code working:

```
GLfloat *vbuffer = new GLfloat[24] {
    0,0,0,
    10,0,0,
    0,10,0,
    0,0,10,
    10,10,0,
    10,0,10,
    0,10,10,
    10,10,10
};
GLubyte *cbuffer = new GLubyte[32] {
    255,0,0,255,
    0,255,0,255,
    0,0,255,255,
    255,255,0,255,
    255,0,255,255,
    0,255,255,255,
    0,0,0,255,
    255,255,255,255
};

GLuint *ibuffer = new GLuint[24] {
    0,1,4,2,
    0,2,6,3,
    0,3,5,1,
    1,4,7,5,
    5,7,6,3,
    2,6,7,4
};

//...

glColor4f(1,1,1,1);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY | GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, cbuffer);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vbuffer);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ibuffer);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY | GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

The desired cube isn't drawn, whereas the coordinate axes, which are drawn with `glVertex3f`, always appear.

When I remove the `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` from `glEnableClientState`, the cube is drawn completely white, as instructed.

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't the glColorPointer-stuff working?

---

System:

- Kubuntu 13.04, 64bit
- Intel HD Graphics 3000
- OpenGL 3.0 (Mesa 9.1.7)

Comment: `glGetError()` is your friend if your code does not work as expected. It would have immediately flagged a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error from your `glEnableClientState()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Array identifiers are not bitmasks.

Generally speaking, if it does not take the form `GL_..._BIT` in its name, it is not something you can binary `OR` together to produce something meaningful.

#### To do this correctly, you need:

```
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

By the way, there is really no point in ever disabling `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`. You cannot draw anything without a vertex position, so that state is usually enabled at application init and never touched.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY | GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

is not going to work, `glEnableClientState` takes a `GLenum` as agrument, *not* a `GLbitfield`. Those enum values are not single bits, so the binary OR of them can be anything - this should just generate the `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

You have to enable/disable each array with a separate call:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```